# How to check/uncheck only particular list items in checkBoxlist based on another list item in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkBox list in my aspx page, as follows. The chklstOptions has to allow the user either to select RepOptionA or RepOptionB, and both checkboxes should not be selected at the same time.

For example whenever user selects RepOptionB when the RepOptionA is already checked, the RepOptionA must be unchecked and the RepOptionB should be checked. Additionally, user can check/uncheck the other options like OptionA, OptionB and OptionC without any constraints. Could someone suggest a way to implement this

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstOptions"  runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Enabled="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chklstOptions_SelectedIndexChanged" OnTextChanged="chklstOptions_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
  <asp:ListItem Text="OptionA" Value="OptionA" ></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="OptionB" Value="OptionB" ></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="OptionC" Value="OptionC" ></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="RepOptionA" Value="RepOptionA" ></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="RepOptionB" Value="RepOptionB" ></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

So far, I tried the below code, which is of no help

```
protected void chklstOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem Item in chklstOptions.Items)
    {
        if (Item.Selected)
        {
            if (Item.Text == "RepOptionB")
            {
                if (chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionA").Selected == true)
                                chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionA").Selected = false;
                            chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionB").Selected = true;
                    }
                    if (Item.Text == "RepOptionA")
                    {
                            if (chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionB").Selected == true)
                                chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionB").Selected = false;
                            chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionA").Selected = true;
                    }               
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do it like that?

Comment: In the above code at the selectedIndexChanged event, whenever RepOptionA is selected, and user selects the RepOptionB, the RepOptionA remains checked. I want the RepOptionA to be unchecked and RepOptionB should be checked in this case.

Comment: Solution is to create to CheckboxLists. One for RepoptionA/B and another for the other Options. Otherwise you will not know which one was selected at first,when the user clicks also on the other options. 
You can do it like this, it's doable, but cumbersome, but then you have to store the first selected RepOption --> A or B somewhere on the server and then, deactivate A or B correspondingly. The user won't see in the UI that there are in fact two checkboxlists when you align them accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally implemented it with the below code, using the last selected checkbox listitem value .. :-)

```
protected void chklstOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var selectedItem = chklstOptions.SelectedItem;   
        string result = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
        string[] checkedBox = result.Split('$'); ;
        int index = int.Parse(checkedBox[checkedBox.Length - 1]);
        string latestItem = chklstOptions.Items[index].Value;
        foreach (ListItem Item in chklstOptions.Items)
        {
            if (Item.Selected)
            {
                if (Item.Text == "RepOptionA" && latestItem == "RepOptionB")
                {                    
                        chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionA").Selected = false;
                        chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionB").Selected = true;
                }
                if (Item.Text == "RepOptionB" && latestItem == "RepOptionA") 
                {
                    chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionB").Selected = false;
                    chklstOptions.Items.FindByText("RepOptionA").Selected = true;
                }              
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected void chklstOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListItem lt in chklstOptions.Items)
            {
                if (lt.Value == "RepOptionB")
                    if (lt.Selected)
                    {
                        foreach (ListItem lm in chklstOptions.Items)
                        {
                            if (lm.Value == "RepOptionA")
                                lm.Selected = false;
                        }
                    }
            }
            foreach (ListItem lt in chklstOptions.Items)
            {
                if (lt.Value == "RepOptionA")
                    if (lt.Selected)
                    {

                        foreach (ListItem lm in chklstOptions.Items)
                        {
                            if (lm.Value == "RepOptionB")
                                lm.Selected = false;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```